# Get element on any level of an object in Javasscript

Tags: javascript, json, object

Given the following:

```
var a = JSON.parse('{"fst":"data1","snd":{"ind2":"data2"}}');
var index = "fst";
var res = a[index]; //res = data1
var index2 = "????";
var res2 = a[index2]; //res = data2
```

what should I put on `index2` so `res2` equals `data2`?

I'm looking for a generic syntax that would let me grab an element at ANY level of the parsed json, just by modifying the index string.

(I'm looping through a list of elements from different places/levels of a json derived object to build a table)

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function for that

```
function deepAccess( obj, str ) {
    var parts = str.split("."),
        cur = obj;
    for( var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i ) {
        cur = cur[parts[i]];    
    }

    return cur;
}

var index = "fst";
deepAccess( a, index ); //"data1"
index = "snd.ind2";
deepAccess( a, index ); //"data2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing a property of a property, and the syntax reflects this:

```
var res = a['snd']['ind2'];
```

There is no way to directly grab the "nested" property directly. If you're allowed to change the original object, you could add shortcut accessors for each object:

```
//Credit goes to Esailja for the original
function deepAccess(obj) {
    function nestedAccess(o, level) {
        if (typeof o == "object") {
            var level = level || "";
            for (p in o) {
                if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    if (level && typeof(o[p]) != "object") {
                        obj[level + "." + p] = o[p];
                    }
                    nestedAccess(o[p], (level ? level + "." : "") + p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    nestedAccess(obj);
}

deepAccess(a);

a["snd.ind2"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Esailja's seems simpler to implement.

Comment: @Henry Definitely. I just came up with this because I thought it would be interesting to add shortcuts for all properties at all levels of the object, which makes it easier to use. See the usage at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
var someObject1 = {};
var someObject2 = {e01: '*', e02: {e03: '*', e04: '*'}, e05: '*'};
var someObject3 = {e01: {e02: {e03: '*'}}};

function setValueByPath(obj, path, value) {
    var pathArray = path.split('.');

    function goDownstears(o, chunk, val) {
        var prop = chunk.shift();

        if(!o.hasOwnProperty(prop)) o[prop] = {};

        o[prop] = (chunk.length > 0) ? goDownstears(o[prop], chunk, val) : val;

        return o;
    }

    obj = goDownstears(obj, pathArray, value);
}

setValueByPath(someObject1, 'e01.e02.e03', 'changed');

setValueByPath(someObject2, 'e02.e04', 'changed');

setValueByPath(someObject3, 'e01.e02.e03', 'changed');
setValueByPath(someObject3, 'e01.e02.e04', 'changed');
setValueByPath(someObject3, 'e02.e01.e01', 'changed');

console.log(someObject1);
console.log(someObject2);
console.log(someObject3);
```

My question was closed here [set an object property with sugar like obj['level1.level2.leve3'] = value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563093/set-an-object-property-with-sugar-like-objlevel1-level2-leve3-value)

See here http://jsfiddle.net/zafod/RDGwY

This issue is for setting a value, but you can just return an asked property througth iterations