# set an object property with sugar like obj['level1.level2.leve3'] = value

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get element on any level of an object in Javasscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534116/get-element-on-any-level-of-an-object-in-javasscript)

Good day for every one!
I'am really confused with this one:

I have an Object:

```
var someObject = {}
```

So, next I wanna set properties like this:

```
someObject['errors.email'] = value1;

someObject['errors.password'] = value2;
```

and after have an object:

```
{
   errors: {
              email: 'some value 1'
              ,password: 'some value 2'
           }
}
```

is it possible with some syntactic sugar?

## The most sweet issue is

```
function setValueByPath(obj, path, value) {
var pathArray = path.split('.');
    var pointer = obj;
    var i = 0, l = pathArray.length-1, prop;

    for (; i<l; i++) {
        prop = pathArray[i];
        pointer = pointer.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? pointer[prop] : (pointer[prop] = {});
    }

    pointer[pathArray[i]] = value;
}
```

thanks to Roman Ziva for advice (see here http://jsperf.com/autocreate-obj)

an example see here http://jsfiddle.net/zafod/KxesD/

Comment: You can use a function to parse the `someObject` when you wanna get its value.

Comment: you can't set properties like that, instead of that set like this, someObject['errors']['email'] = value1;

someObject['errors']['password'] = value2;

Comment: @Rajagopal in case you provided I have an error "Can not set property 'email' of undefined" - it means in construction someObject['errors']['email'] = value1 'errors' property is undefined

Comment: @Niul, I wanna SET values first!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the properties like this,

```
var errors = someObject['errors'] = {};
errors['email'] = value1;
errors['password'] = value2;
```

Else,

```
someObject['errors'] = { "email": value1, "validation": {"fatal": {"email": value2}}}
```

There is no other best option for this.

Comment: Vote up and accept the answer if it helps! If it doesn't work, what is the issue you have faced on this code?

Comment: Yeah! I' ve found it the first! But it's a bit difficult to set property by path like 'errors.validation.fatal.email'

Comment: Just now i have edited my answer

Comment: I solve it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534116/get-element-on-any-level-of-an-object-in-javasscript/13568138#13568138